# How to distinguish words hare, here, hair, heir, hire, her, higher, hear?

Tags: pronunciation

How can I distinguish between the words 'hare', 'here', 'hair', 'heir', 'hire', 'her', 'higher' and 'hear' when pronounced?

Comment: Some of these have additional homonyms: "air" ("heir"); "higher" ("hire); "hear" ("here"). Also, "error" and "era" are very similar to "air", particularly in AmE.

Comment: Kaz, "error" and "era" are not similar to "air" or each other, in the UK.

Comment: *Error* and *era* are similar in a Boston or New York accent perhaps, but this Californian would recoil at such pronunciation.

Comment: _Higher_ and _hire_ as homophones?  Are there people who pronounce  _higher_ as a one-syllable word?

Comment: @Kaz - that sounds very Louisiana/Mississippi. choster - I don't think that would be a Boston accent (usually elongate the vowel before an R and drop the R. Car becomes /kaaaah/)

Comment: @Adam do u pronounce hire with one syllable? Is it possible at all?

Comment: @Adam. Many native speakers pronounce both *higher* and *hire* as /haɪə(r)/.

Comment: I pronounce _hire_ to rhyme with _fire_, and _higher_ to rhyme with _flyer_.  (AmE, Oregon (_Orgin_))

Comment: @Adam and what's the difference between the first two and the last two? I was taught all these words should be pronounced "-ə(r)"

Comment: @Anixx The difference is subtle, and I guess not universal among English speakers.  When I say _"firehose,"_  the prefix _fire_ is solidly one syllable.  I keep most of that pronunciation when _fire_ stands alone - the "r" doesn't make a new syllable as much as it draws out and turns down the end the first syllable a little.  In _higher_, though, there is a clear syllable break, and two clear syllables.  Maybe it is a matter of speed - _hire_ at 130 WPM = _higher_ at 180?

Answer (score 7):

Please be aware that the pronunciation could vary from one dialect to another.

However, the words you mentioned seem to be pronounced pretty much the same in both American (AmE) and English (BrE) accents. One main difference here is that BrE is typically non-rhotic ([r] sound is more gentle and subtle), while AmE is typically rhotic.

**heir** is pronounced "air"
**hare** and **hair** are pronounced "hair" (with the same vowel as "air")
**here** rhymes with "ear", but with "h" sound
**hire** rhymes with "fire", but with "h" sound
**her** is pronounced "her"

Your dictionary should provide another good way to check the pronunciation.

Finally, thanks to @Hellion, in listening, to tell which word is which from several possible homophones (e.g. *heir* or *air*), context will give you necessary clues.

Comment: The biggest difference here is that BrE is typically non-rhotic, while AmE is typically rhotic.

Comment: How do you distinguish "air" and "heir"? What's difference between "hire" and "hair"?

Comment: You said "heir" should be pronounced without the initial consonant, did not you? If it is pronounced with a consonant, how do you distinguich it from "hair"? What is difference between [-ire] and [-air]?

Comment: I'm really sorry, I misread *heir* as *hair*. This following should be correct. Air and heir sounds identical. Air and hair are different in their initial consonants (glottal stop vs. [h] sound). Hire and hair are different in their vowel sounds ([-ire] vs. [-air]). For the real sound of [hire] and [hair], http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hire and http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hair will help.

Comment: Damkerng T., what you're describing as not pronounced, is in practice, simply subtle. If the letter *r* was not pronounced, it would be silent, which is not reality.

Comment: @Tristan Agreed. When I listened to radio or watched TV, I usually found that quite often enough, [r] sound wasn't entirely discarded in most BrE speakers. But I couldn't figure out the exact pattern of this BrE [r] sound. Do you have a better suggestion for describing this non-rhotic in BrE accent?

Comment: Yes, a realistic, accurate description would be that it's a gentle, subtle *r* sound.

Comment: @Anixx, you distinguish between *heir* and *air* the same way you distinguish between other homophones: context.

Comment: @Hellion It seems that I might misinterpret OP's intention. Thank you for pointing this out. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I distinguish between the words 'hare', 'here', 'hair', 'heir', 'hire', 'her', 'higher' and 'hear' when pronounced?

Context.  Here's some hints that can help you.

- *hare* isn't too common of a word unless the conversation involves rabbits or animals, the expression *hare-brained* being a possible exception.  So you can assume "hair" if you hear this most of the time.
- *hear* is a verb and will be immediately preceded by a subject pronoun most of the time - I hear X... etc.  *here* will not be immediately preceded by a subject pronoun.  *hear* can be the first word of a sentence, but not too often - using *hear* in the imperative sense, where it would be the first word of the sentence, would be limited to an announcement scenario, or possibly where someone is telling you to listen closely.
- *heir* isn't a common word outside of a royal or legal setting.  Nine times out of ten this sound is the word *air*.
- *hire* is a verb and will be immediately preceded by a subject pronoun most of the time, or be used in the expression *for hire*.  *Higher*, being an modifier, will not.  EDIT: *hire* is also a noun, typically used in the phrase *new hire* or *recent hire.*
- *her* should not sound like the other words, but this could be the case in some dialects.  Usually *her* will occur towards the end of a sentence and preceded by a preposition like "to" or "by."  If it occurs towards the beginning of a sentence, it will be immediately followed by a noun, expressing possession - "Her face was beautiful."

Comment: _hire_ isn't always a verb.  _Have you met the new hire?  She is really smart._

Comment: Good point.  Editing.